# Facing "error publishing to Tomcat v6.0 server at localhost has encountered a failure"

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6

I am facing a problem when i try to run eclipse in debug mode. I have added the app jar to tomcat 6.0 in eclipse and when i try to debug or start the tomcat server it throwing this error over and over again. I have tried to run eclipse in admin mode but even that does not help. PFB the error details!

> Publishing the configuration... Error copying file to
>   C:/Software/Softwares/apache-tomcat-6.0.41/backup\server.out.xml:
>   C:\Software\Softwares\apache-tomcat-6.0.41\conf\server.out.xml (The
>   system cannot find the file specified)
>   C:\Software\Softwares\apache-tomcat-6.0.41\conf\server.out.xml (The
>   system cannot find the file specified)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was to remove the tomcat server v6.0 from eclipse and add again.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have the file server.out.xml file on your conf folder from tomcat. I suggest you to check if you change your configuration of tomcat. I have tomcat 7 and this file isn't on my conf folder. Also you can try download a newer version of tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

create empty file "**server.out.xml** " in *C:\Software\Softwares\apache-tomcat-6.0.41\conf* and *C:/Software/Softwares/apache-tomcat-6.0.41/backup*